# Reading dynamic checkbox array in php/html

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, html, checkbox

I have multiple form fields which are created dynamically .

```
<label><input type="text" name="txtAmt[]">Amount</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="cbMarkPaid[]">Mark as Paid</label>
```

I use post method to submit the for to php file.I know that the checkbox won't send the data to the server when you did not check it.But i want to know the indices of the checkboxes which are not checked.

E.g. If i have 4 checkboxes cb1,cb2,cb3,cb4 and if cb3,cb4 is checked . then php recieves an array with two items :

> array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "on" [1]=> string(2) "on" }

But i want the array to be as:

> array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "off" [1]=> string(2) "off" [2]=> string(2) "on" [3]=> string(2) "on"}.

Please not `isset($_POST['cbMarkPaid'][])` is also giving the same output
Thank you

Comment: Do share complete markup... You have provided only 2 fields...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with a checkbox over POST. By definition, [unchecked checkboxes are never successful](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2).

> A successful control is "valid" for submission.
>   All "on" checkboxes may be successful.

The best you can do is to index your array and look for the gaps. For example

```
<label><input type="text" name="txtAmt[0]">Amount</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="cbMarkPaid[0]">Mark as Paid</label>
<label><input type="text" name="txtAmt[1]">Amount</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="cbMarkPaid[1]">Mark as Paid</label>
```

Let's say you leave the first unchecked and the second checked. Then your array will look like

> array(1) { [1]=> string(2) "on" }

So you know `[0]` was off since it wasn't submitted